# Xamarin Android Grid control

Tags: c#, android, xamarin

Is there a suitable grid control in Xamarin Android, table-like, for a business app that supports databindind with collections that help altering various columns/cells?
As far as I find out, there are alternatives only by inheriting an existing control like ListView and creating a custom control.
If a control as one I am searching for does not exist, what could be the best option left?
Many thanks in advance!!

Answer (score 1):

> Is there a suitable grid control in Xamarin Android, table-like, for a business app that supports databindind with collections that help altering various columns/cells?

You can refer to [GridView](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/android/user_interface/layouts/grid-view/), it displays items in a two-dimensional, scrollable grid.

And this [tutorial](https://developer.xamarin.com/recipes/android/layout/grid_view/create_a_grid_view/) will show how to create a Grid View.

Comment: thank you for your answer Grace, but as far as I saw, this control does not have a data source and databind methods. I need a grid in which i can  dynamically modify data both ways(UI to datasource, datasource to UI), parse rows to objects, etc. If i miss something please highlight. thanks!

Comment: @AlexSen, you're developing a Xamarin Android project, not Xamarin Forms, there is no official pattern of data binding between .axml layout and data in code behind. Also, data binding in project like UWP, usually there is no meaning to use two-way binding for collection source, for the collection it should be one-way binding from source to control, hence you can directly set collection to this `GridView` in code behind. And adding data to source will be displayed in the view.